# ffmpeg multi-resoutions outputs with same/different filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I am encoding multiple resolutions as follows

```
fmpeg -i source.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=50:50[wm];[wm]scale=-2:480:flags=lanczos" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 22 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k out_480.mp4

fmpeg -i source.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=50:50[wm];[wm]scale=-2:360:flags=lanczos" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 21 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k out_360.mp4
```

and a few more resolutions.

I am trying to do this with a single command as per (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) so I can optimize the encoding process however, my command has one common watermark filter and the scaling filter which will be independent for each output.

What's the best way to encode these multiple resolutions out so ffmpeg only applies watermark once to source and encodes the audio once as well but gets me different resolutions out at different CRF levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tee muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1) is available for cloning output streams to multiple outputs.

Fir your set of commands,

`ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=50:50,split=2[wm480][wm360];[wm480]scale=-2:480:flags=lanczos[v480];[wm360]scale=-2:360:flags=lanczos[v360]" -map [v480] -map [v360] -map 0:a -flags:v +global_header -c:v libx264 -preset:v fast -crf:v:0 22 -crf:v:1 21 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']out_480.mp4|[select=\'v:1,a\']out_360.mp4"`

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try this out.. Out of curiosity, is the global_header needed or just to reduce the overhead?

Comment: It's required for video streams stored in MP4, but when saved via tee, needs to be manually specified.